# how to end my writing on file without enter in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

I'm doing an iteration on a dictionary and writing the items on a file, as you know there is no enter after each line, so i have to write \n at the end.
for the last line that is going to write, the \n is also there. which means if the dictionary has 4 items, the output is 5 lines (the last one is just an enter)how can i make it 4 ?

```
dic = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

for k, v in dic.items():
f_handle.write('%s is %i\n' % (k, v))
```

output is:

```
a is 1
b is 2
c is 3
d is 4
      #\n
```

Comment: For the record, a trailing newline is considered good practice for files.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `join` to avoid writing a trailing newline:

```py
f_handle.write("\n".join("%s is %i" % (k, v) for k, v in dic.items()))
```